# How to write a customized for() function

Tags: r, for-loop

Is there a way to write a custom `for()` function that behaves identically to `for()` but does a few extra things?

What I would like to do is have a modified `for()` function that starts a progress bar.

As an example, currently I use `progress::progress_bar()` as follows when I want to display progress through a loop:

```
pb <- progress_bar$new(total = 100)
for (i in 1:100) {
  pb$tick()
  Sys.sleep(1 / 100)
}
```

What I would like is to be able to have a function that does something like this:

```
for_pb <- function(var in seq, ...) {
  pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(total=length(seq))
  for(var in seq) {
    pb$tick()
    ... #The rest of the code in the for loop
  }
}
```

And as a result, the following call would produce the same output as the initial example:

```
for_pb(i in 1:100) {
  Sys.sleep(1 / 100)
}
```

Comment: You can look at `plyr` package and its function like `llply`, `alply`, ... which include a progress bar if you use `.progress` argument in the function. It is a way to do iteration with a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't apply to what I need this for (file operations, imagemagick manipulations).

Comment: you can do everything that implies loop operation with `plyr`, included what you describe. It is really just a way of doing loop like for but without for.
for operation that are doing something but do not return anything `l_ply` works for that